# Header file not executing if else case

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, header-files

My project contains 3 targets and it requires some credential details specific to target. I have defines.h file where I am checking the current target and then initialising constants.

```
#ifdef XYZ44DEV

#define COM_CMS_URL                     @"http://xyz.portal.com"
#define COM_CMS_USER                    @"test"
#define COM_CMS_PASS                    @"test"

#elif XYZ44UAT

#define COM_CMS_URL                     @"http://xyz.uat.portal.com"
#define COM_CMS_USER                    @"uat"
#define COM_CMS_PASS                    @"uat"

#else

#define COM_CMS_URL                     @"http://xyz.prod.portal.com"
#define COM_CMS_USER                    @"Prod"
#define COM_CMS_PASS                    @"Prod"

#endif
```

Any target I run, it goes to else case and takes COM_CMS_USER & COM_CMS_PASS as "Prod". Please let me know, what i am missing here.

Comment: have you add this defines.h file in .pch file.... if not then add #import "Defines.h" in .pch file... Hopw it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add preprocessor Macros in build settings as illustrated in image

[image]

the output for

```
NSLog(@"%@",COM_CMS_USER);
```

is

```
2016-05-20 11:58:05.315 CustomKeyboard[2952:687530] test
```

Comment: is it ok if I have spaces in my target; like XYZ 44 DEV or XYZ 44 PROD ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set preprocessing macro in build setting [image: You have to add macro for each your target]

[image: For macro , you can set only supported versions]

image 1 : You have to add macro for each your target
image 2 : For macro , you can set only supported versions